# TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'addListener')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Feel there are many similar issues just like this one out there, but none seem to have the solution for me. This is definitely not a code related issue, everything worked perfectly, I ran an update and now I can't get passed this error, some packages clearly don't work together.

Here is my stack trace:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'addListener')

This error is located at:
    in CardStack (at CardStackTransitioner.js:67)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at Transitioner.js:142)
    in Transitioner (at CardStackTransitioner.js:19)
    in CardStackTransitioner (at StackNavigator.js:41)
    in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:13)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:226)
    in NavigationContainer (at Router.js:70)
    in App (at Router.js:91)
    in Router (at Router.js:10)
    in RouterComponent (at App.js:41)
    in Provider (at App.js:40)
    in App (at registerRootComponent.js:35)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:34)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
- node_modules\react-native-router-flux\node_modules\react-navigation\src\getChildEventSubscriber.js:72:60 in <unknown>
- node_modules\react-native-router-flux\node_modules\react-navigation\src\getChildEventSubscriber.js:72:45 in getChildEventSubscri
ber
- ... 28 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Here are my current dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^25.0.1",
    "firebase": "^4.13.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.52.3",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.30",
    "react-native-scripts": "^1.14.0",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^1.0.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.0",
    "jest-expo": "^25.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
```

Hope somebody has encountered this issue with the same depencies as me!

Many Thanks,

Adam

Comment: Googling literally the first error line gives this: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2897 - it seems to be an issue with react native router flux. Try deleting all node_modules and then rebuilding.

Comment: also potentially related: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3468

Answer (score 0):

Found what worked for me:

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn cache clean
yarn install
```

As seen in comments here: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2799